# simple CLASS in python

Tags: python

```
from math import pi

class sphere(object):

    def __init__(self,radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def get_radius(self):
        return radius

    def surfaceArea(self):
        return 4*pi*radius**2

    def volume(self):
        return (4//3)*pi*radius**3

radius = input("Please enter your radius:")

print sphere.get_radius()
print sphere.surfaceArea()
print sphere.volume()
```

i need to write the program that prompts the user for a radius then uses your sphere class to output the surface area and volume of a sphere. and I get a type error unbound method get_Radius() must be called with sphere instance as first argument(got nothing instead). Any way to solve this problemo?

Comment: @MartinWang : Huh??? It's a simple class instantiation problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have never created an object from class sphere.  Instead of calling sphere.get_radius(), you need to first initiate an object from that class, then call the method on that object.

```
a = sphere(radius)  # initiate an object of class sphere called a
a.get_radius()  # call method on the object a.
```

Answer (score 0):

- you need to create a new object and assign redius variable
- You need also to use self.redius inside the class.

Check the code below for the above mentioned-comments

```
from math import pi

class sphere(object):

    def __init__(self,radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def get_radius(self):
        return self.radius

    def surfaceArea(self):
        return 4*pi*self.radius**2

    def volume(self):
        return (4//3)*pi*self.radius**3

radius = input("Please enter your radius:")

s= sphere(radius)
print s.get_radius()
print s.surfaceArea()
print s.volume()
```